Quantum Fisher information between two discrete probability distributions
I will be thankful in advance if you help me find the problem. Between two discrete probability distributions
$D(p\|q)=\sum_k(p_k \log(p_k/q_k) )$ or $D(p(t+ \Delta t)\|p(t))=\sum_k( (\frac{d}{dt} p_k) /p_k )(\Delta t)^2$ that $\Delta t$ is very small. I have a density matrix from the master equation, $p$ and $q$ are population and $H_S$ is the Hamiltonian of the system. I write a code for that but I don't know what is the problem in the code that the result $I_E$ for the initial and separate initial state is the same.
evecs = HS.eigenstates()
P_k = projectors(HS)
delta_t = tlist[1] - tlist[0]

for i in range(len(tlist) - 1):
rho_t = result.states[i]
rho_t_plus_dt = result.states[i + 1]

p_k_t = probabilities(rho_t, P_k)
p_k_t_plus_dt = probabilities(rho_t_plus_dt, P_k)


log_probabilities = np.log2(p_k_t/ p_k_t_plus_dt)
d_log_probabilities_dt = np.gradient(log_probabilities, tlist, axis=0)

I_E_t = np.sum((d_log_probabilities_dt ** 2) * probabilities_t, axis=1)

